# Redux - how unsubscribe listener works?

Tags: javascript, redux, unsubscribe

I am new to Redux. 
I wonder what unsubscribe listener fundamentally is and how it works? 
I know that register function returns an unsubscribe but in the following example when we call the unsubscribe method why it does not just trigger a new  function nested inside the variable? As we can see:

```
let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {  
    // let unsubscribe nests a function   
    // execute every time the state changes
    const state = store.getState(); 
});
// but here instead of call the nested function it cancels the listener, how is it possible ?
unsubscribe();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think it is a little late to answer this question, but to be more clear, I would like to present it.
Key things to keep in mind are:

1. What exactly is `store.subscribe`, take a demo of the youtube `subscribe` option (and bell icon), now whenever channel admin uploads a new video, it instantly calls listener(i.e. subscribe) here and gets you notified, now if you unsubscribe then you won't get notified. Simple enough!
2. `store.subscribe` or say the listener function is called whenever the state is changed because of the dispatched action.
3. return type of the subscribe function is again a function the `unsubscribes` the change listener.

```js
//Action is an object with type property
const BUY_CAKE = 'BUY_CAKE'; 

// Action creator is a function that returns an actions 
function buyCake() {
  return {
    type: BUY_CAKE,
    info: 'first redux action',
  }
}

// initial state for reducer, Reducer -> (previousstate, action) =>newState
const initialState = {
  numOfCakes: 10
}

// This is our reducer function 
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BUY_CAKE: return {
      ...state,  // making the copy of state object
      numOfCakes: state.numOfCakes - 1
    }
    default: return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer);
console.log("initial state", store.getState());
/*Returns the current state tree of your application. It is equal to the last value returned by the store's reducer.*/

// The subscribe listerner will be called eveytime an action is dispatched
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => console.log("updated state", store.getState()))
store.dispatch(buyCake());
store.dispatch(buyCake());
unsubscribe();
store.dispatch(buyCake());
console.log("state after unsubscribe", store.getState());
```

This will give the output

```js
initial state { numOfCakes: 10 }
updated state { numOfCakes: 9 }
updated state { numOfCakes: 8 }
state after unsubscribe { numOfCakes: 7 }
```

So you see, after unsubscribing the listener is not called automatically. So here is the final catch

> As you call the `unsubscribe`, it is a function which is returned from the `subscribe` function so it does not call the subscribe function again, rather call another function which `unsubscribes the change listener`.

Answer (score 1):

the unsubscribe function in redux is actually implemented inside the subscribe method in redux createStore method. Here is how it works:

```
//Inside store
    const subscribe = (listener) => {
           listeners.push(listener);
           return () => {
           listeners.filter(l => l !== listener);
        };
        };
// End of inside store 

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange)
unsubscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

We are invoking store.subscribe() and passing it a callback function. That callback gets called whenever the store changes.

The function signature explains that subscribe expects a function that will be invoked on every dispatch and returns a function that when invoked will unsubscribe the listener. imagine like this:

```
function store.subscribe(callback){ 
    //execute the callback function
    callback();
    return store.unsubscribe()
}
```